# Word 2013 - insert "intelligent" field

Tags: microsoft-word, macros

I have a word document with several sections and every section has a unique header. I need to insert a field containing the revision date, and as it is now I need to insert the date in all the sections. 
Is there a way to do this so I only need to type the revision date in one time?